# jBox ajax firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jbox

I'm having a small problem with ajax requests being fired multiple times using the jBox tooltips jquery plugin.

I basically have a form setup within a tooltip displayed using ajax. The first time I submit the form (via ajax), it submits only once. However, if I close and open the tooltip multiple times and then submit the form again, it'll fire for as many times as I opened the tooltip.

How do you stop this?

This is my code to initiate the jBox tooltips:

```
var tooltip = new jBox('Tooltip', {
    attach: $('.tooltip'),
    onOpen: function(){
        // Get the ajax url if it's set
        if (this.source.data('ajax-url') != undefined) {
            this.options.ajax.url = this.source.data('ajax-url');
        } else {
            this.options.ajax.url = null;
        }
    },
    preventDefault: true,
    trigger: 'click',
    closeOnClick: 'body',
    width: 350,
    height: 'auto',
    zIndex: 1000,
    ajax: {
        reload: true,
        cache: false,
        setContent: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you binding the tooltip on every click?

Comment: How is `tooltip` used elsewhere? This code snippet shows the creation of the new object, but it doesn't show your calls to tell it to open.

Comment: The object is attached to any $('.tooltip') class. The documentation recommends this format in order to access the jBox methods i.e. tooltip.close() or tooltip.destroy().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to fix this. It was because my ajax submit form code was in the ajax loaded template when it should have been within the main document.